# Adding text outside plot doesn't work in r

Tags: r, plot

I have a simple dataset:
11 observations, 1 variable.

I want to plot them adding my own axis names, but when I want to change the position of them, R keeps plotting them in the exact same spot.

Here is my script:

```
plot(data[,5], xlab = "", xaxt='n')
axis(1, at = 1:11, labels = F)
text(1:11, par("usr")[3] - 0.1, srt = 90, adj = 1, labels = names, xpd = TRUE)
```

I am changing the `-0.1`, to any number but R keeps placing the labels in the exact same spot. I tried with short names like `"a"` but the result is the same.

Thanks in advance

My data:

```
10308.9
10201.6
12685.3
3957.93
7677.1
9671.7
11849.4
10755.7
11283.4
11583.8
12066.9

names <- rep("name",11)
```

Comment: why not use axis to make your axis labels instead of text?

Comment: also, `?mtext` is for plot margins

Comment: Is there a way to change the positions of the labels using `axis`? I explored the ?axis page but couldn't find it. If the problem can be solved using labels that would great!

Comment: the `at` arg is where the `labels` will go

Comment: I am trying with mtext and axis but I can't do it. Could you show me which parameters to use so I can have the `mtext` the same way I wanted it using `text`?

Comment: you should add your data so we can work with it. based on your code I would guess `axis(1, at = 1:11, labels = names, las = 2)` You can use `las` in `axis` to rotate like you are doing with `srt` in `text`. Note that `text` only plots within the x- and y limits, so you can't label the axes with text since the axis labels are outside of the x/y limits (usually). But without your data, I can't say for sure

Comment: I uploaded my data. I tried using `las`, but there is not a parameter for doing a 45 degrees rotation of the axis.

Answer (score 1):

My `ggplot` solution:

```
# creating the sample dataframe
data <- read.table(text="10308.9
10201.6
12685.3
3957.93
7677.1
9671.7
11849.4
10755.7
11283.4
11583.8
12066.9", header=FALSE)

# adding a names column
data$names <- as.factor(paste0("name",sprintf("%02.0f", seq(1,11,1))))

#creating the plot
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=names, y=V1)) + 
  geom_bar(fill = "white", color = "black")
```

which gives:
[image]

When you want to change the order of the bars, you can do that with transform:

```
# transforming the data (I placed "name04" as the first one)
data2 <- transform(data,
                   newnames=factor(names,
                                   levels=c("name04","name01","name02","name03","name04","name05","name06","name07","name08","name09","name10","name11"),
                                   ordered =TRUE))

#creating the plot
ggplot(data2, aes(x=newnames, y=V1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="white", color="black")
```

which gives:
[image]